# how to use class in library with hints

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries, jsdoc

I created a Google script without a container with this code and deployed it as a library.

```
/** 
 * @class
 */
class Table5 {

  constructor(ss_id){
    this.ss_id = ss_id;
  }

  /**
   * GetSheet5
   * @param {string} sheet_id - sheet id
   * @memberof Table5#
   */
  GetSheet5(sheet_id){
    console.log(`ss_id="${this.ss_id}", sheet_id="${sheet_id}"`)
  }
}

/**
 * Table5
 * @constructs
 * @param {string} ss_id - ss_id
 */
let new_point = (ss_id) => new Table5(ss_id)
```

I expect to see a tooltip or autocomplete after `MyLib.new_point().` in my application code, but they are not there. Tell me, what is the reason?

I suspect that the problem is in the correct JSDoc tags, but I was not able to select them correctly. there is no auto-completion of class prototype functions.

tips is here, if in script[image]

no tips, if in lib[image]

UPDATE

Everything seems to work correctly with these headers.
Adds @return to new_point():

```
    /** @lends new_point.prototype */
class Table5 {

  /** @constructor */
  constructor(ss_id){
    this.ss_id = ss_id;
  }

  /**
   * GetSheet5
   * @memberof Table5#
   * @param {string} sheet_id - sheet id
   */
  GetSheet5(sheet_id){
    console.log(`ss_id="${this.ss_id}", sheet_id="${sheet_id}"`)
  }

}


/**
 * This is a description of the Table5 constructor function.
 * @class
 * @classdesc This is a description of the Table5 class.
 * @param {string} ss_id - ss_id
 * @return {Table5}
 */
let new_point = (ss_id) => new Table5(ss_id)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script, `and deployed it as a library` and your current issue. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sure. I also apologize for my English. I'll try to explain again. When in my code I type MyLib.new_point().GetSheet5() - it works. But if I forget the prototype name "GetSheet5" it will be a problem because there is no hint, the prototype name does not appear after entering a dot after the new_point() method. there are tips if this code is in a script, but there are no tips when the code is in a library